# Could Someone Please Tell Me Which Language Should I Use

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

Hi guys please could you help do this I tried to read about jquery, ajax, json, curl but I just got really lost so I am asking for help to guide me to the right way and thank you so much.

What I want to do is this :
take this from in html

```
<form method="GET" action="https://exemple.com/.../api/work.php">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="link"/>
<input type="text" name="params[login]"  value="ready" />
</br><input type="text" name="params[pass]"  value="download"/></br>
<input type="text" size="80" name="params[link]" placeholder="get ready"/></br>
  <input type="submit" formtarget="txt" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And turn it to this

```
<form>
<input type="text" size="80" name="params[link]" placeholder="get ready"/></br>
  <input type="submit" formtarget="txt" value="Submit">
</form>
<iframe type="hidden" name="txt"></iframe>
```

I want to validate
- the the first input with name="method" value="link"
-the second input with name="params[login]"  value="ready"
-the third input with name="params[pass]"  value="download"
to this url https://exemple.com/api/work.php ( This is a different domain "cross domain") with the GET request

The API that I am using is private I talk to them and they told me that I can share it but I don't want to share my username and password but I want to share the possibility to check the url using mine the request should be like this.

https://exemple.com/...loadlink[login]=USERNAME&params[pass]=PASSWORD&params[link]=LINK
that's how it should be submitted. 
conclusion

I don't want the visitor the see the url or the 3 inputs they can pnly submit the link they want to check.

Thank you so much I hope someone can guide me to the right way I am so lost now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your password to show, you'll need to do the actual API call using a server-side language - PHP might be a good one. Doing an HTTP request using it is a simple matter of using `file_get_contents($URL)` these days.

This means that you will need to pass it the values from the client. Two choices: JavaScript (through AJAX), or a plain old HTTP request.

One thing, though. If the URL structure you've given is correct, whoever wrote that API needs to be shot as there is a blatant possibility for CSRF abuse on this.

Comment: So it is possible to send a GET request using php to another php in another domain with the parametre i mentioned before using file_get_contents($URL) ??

Comment: Of course. PHP is not limited by domains when it comes to HTTP requests - only JavaScript is!

Comment: SO should i use CURL ?? and thank you for your time